# Grouping report columns

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have the following data loaded in to crystal report

```
ID  Name            Amt     Cat_1   Cat_2
==  ====            =====   =====   =====
001 CASH            20.00   NULL    NULL
001 CASH            30.00   NULL    NULL
001 CASH            44.00   NULL    NULL
002 CHEQUE          110.00  001     NULL
003 ELECR TRASFERS  6.00    001     NULL
```

I want to group these records by their ID and the amount field should then be totaled. It needs to be like when we do a standard `GROUP BY ID` on SQL.

I used the group expert on Crystal Report & Selected the ID field from the drop-down. Then the grouping worked properly but the Amt is shown as 20 instead it needs to be 94.

Comment: Of course you didn't provide the application, but shouldn't an ID be unique?

Comment: I don't have a primary key to this table, these are entries made by the user & its like a log. So the ID will be duplicated, but for the purpose of the report they need to be grouped & totaled.

Comment: where did you place the `Amt` in crystal report?

Comment: In the Group Header Section of the report.

Comment: that is the issue... istead of group header place `amt` in detail and take summary in group footer you will get the result

Comment: If I place it in the detail section all the records will be displayed, I want each ID to be displayed only once.

Comment: then your outpur of `20` is correct... if you need to get `94` then follow the process suggested....

Comment: Can you post it as an answer, so that I can accept it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get the `Sum` don't place the `amt` in group header which will pick only `first value`.

To get the required outout place the `amt` in detail and take sum in group footer.